# On-event stop recurrence

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asynchronous, recursion

I have a web app with the following HTML line:

```html
<select id="dropdown"; onchange="update()">
```

and the associated JS is:

```js
function update()
{
    val = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
    arr = some_dict[val];
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
    i = 0;

    function recursive_call()
    {
        data = arr.slice(CHUNK_SIZE*i, CHUNK_SIZE*i + CHUNK_SIZE);
        if (data.length < CHUNK_SIZE){return;}
        ...
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/page",
            data: {"data": data},
            async: true,
            success: function (d){
                setTimeout(another_func, 3000);
                recursive_call();
            }
        })
        i++;
    }

}
```

Essentially, whenever a new dropdown value is selected, I recursively extract consecutive chunks from an array and send them to my server. When the array length is less than the chunk size, I return, stopping this process.

The issue is when a new dropdown value is selected and the recursion is incomplete. I would like to stop the existing recurring loop when a new value is selected, and beginning recurring for a new array associated with the new value.

I have tried a few things but the code is super messy and would further convolute what I have described here.

Comment: how about instead of a recursive function you use `setInterval` and then `clearInterval` when the next change event happens? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval the trick will be to save the return value of `setInterval()` to a variable with the right scope so you can cancel it from your event callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of similar functionality using intervals instead of recursion.

The benefit of this is you can cancel an interval with `clearInterval`

```js
let intervalReference = null
let counter = 0

function update() {
   counter = 0
   if(intervalReference !== null){
        clearInterval(intervalReference)
   }
  
  intervalReference = setInterval(()=>{
   counter++
   console.log(counter)
        //do your ajax in here
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" onchange="update()">
 <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```